# Why does Azure B2C refuse to accept <ContentDefinitions> and <Localization> in my custom policy if it comes before <ClaimsTransformations>?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am building a custom Azure B2C Policy. It is built on top of the B2C Starter Pack of policies, and my policy inherits the provided `B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions`. The policy is already working just fine. Now, I want to do some UI customization and I am trying to add a `<ContentDefinitions>` section and a `<Localization>` section in my `<BuildingBlocks>`.

Except, every single time I add a `<ContentDefinitions>` section or a `<Localization>` section B2C complains that the `<ClaimsTransformations>` section is now unexpected. But, I found out that if I add the `<ContentDefinitions>` and `<Localization>` section AFTER the `<ClaimsTransformations>` section it accepts it.

Shouldn't this be agnostic? What difference does it make what order the entries are in? Is this a bug, or something I'm missing?

> The element 'BuildingBlocks' in namespace
> 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06' has invalid
> child element 'ClaimsTransformations' in namespace
> 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06'. List of
> possible elements expected: 'DisplayControls' in namespace
> 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06'

This does not work:

```
  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>{Settings:Tenant}</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>

  <BuildingBlocks>

    <ContentDefinitions/>

    <ClaimsTransformations>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="TEST" TransformationMethod="CreateStringClaim">
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="value" DataType="string" Value="TEST" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" TransformationClaimType="createdClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
    </ClaimsTransformations>

  </BuildingBlocks>
```

This works:

```
  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>{Settings:Tenant}</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>

  <BuildingBlocks>

    <ClaimsTransformations>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="TEST" TransformationMethod="CreateStringClaim">
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="value" DataType="string" Value="TEST" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" TransformationClaimType="createdClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
    </ClaimsTransformations>

    <ContentDefinitions/>

  </BuildingBlocks>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The element 'BuildingBlocks' in namespace
> 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06' has invalid child element 'ClaimsTransformations' in namespace

The above error refers that In the ***Buildingsblocks*** of the chlidren order is not arranged in correct format.

The correct format is

```
 <BuildingBlocks>
    <ClaimsSchema>
      ...
    </ClaimsSchema>
    <Predicates>
    ...
    </Predicates>
    <PredicateValidations>
    ...
    </PredicateValidations>
    <ClaimsTransformations>
      ...
    </ClaimsTransformations>
    <ContentDefinitions>
      ...
    </ContentDefinitions>
    <Localization>
      ...
    </Localization>
    <DisplayControls>
      ...
    </DisplayControls>
 </BuildingBlocks>
```

In your first code you have processed you have arranged like

```
<BuildingBlocks>
     <ContentDefinitions/>
 </BuildingBlocks>
```

Here the children order is wrong that may caused you invalid child element.

In your second code you have arranged in correct order like i given above that why it is worked.

Reference:
[BuildingBlocks - Azure AD B2C | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/buildingblocks)